# Adding buttons to a scroll pane

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am currently using Scene Builder and to design my FXML UI in Java. However when loading the scene, I would like to loop through a user's `devices` and display them as buttons inside a scroll pane:

```
public DeviceSelectorController() {
    for (Device device : OrderBird.getInstance().getProfileManager().getActiveProfile().getDevices()) {
        Label label = new Label(device.getName());
        Button button = new Button(device.getName());
        listView.getItems().add(device.getName());
    }
}
```

I cannot do this through Scene Builder as far as I know because I cannot access the cached `HashMap`.

Comment: Just call a method to add the buttons after the Hashmap is loaded?

Comment: Use an FXML controller to access the scene graph created by loading the associated FXML file.